# Работа с БД на сервере в Android

Tags: android

Хочу написать приложение типа кулинарной книги. Суть в следующем:

1. Есть какой-то хостинг на котором лежит БД с n-количеством рецептов
2. Есть приложение работающее с этой БД

2.1. Пользователь скачав приложение может добавлять новые рецепты (включая картинки)

2.2. Изменять описание своих рецептов.

Оффлайн приложение такого типа написать не проблема. А с онлайн вариантом с чего начать?

Comment: С написания API на стороне сервера, к которому будет обращаться ваше приложение по, например, REST

Comment: А просто закинуть БД на какой-то хостинг и по ссылке к нему обращаться нельзя? :)

Comment: @Kroshka не рекомендуется такое решение.

Comment: Поняла, будем изучать написание API

Comment: А есть статьи как написать api для приложения?

Comment: @Kroshka прям так - только платные. там могут и как рест апи написать рассказать, и как приложение написать под это апи

Comment: пусть платные и бы заплатила и почитала) тема то довольно нужная

Comment: Можно использовать mBaaS сервисы типа Firebase  и Backendless